# Google Analytics: Can't see demographics data

Tags: google-analytics, demographics

I just enabled Demographics feature by making changes via Admin and adding tracking code: `ga('require', 'displayfeatures');`

Anaytics code is like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-49788339-1', 'example.me');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Right now I see this screen. Does it take time or I am doing something wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You asked this question on December 5th, but your date range in Google Analytics only shows data through December 4th.   The first thing you should do is change your date range to include the current day.

It also often takes 24 hours for data to show up in Google Analytics reports.   The second thing you should do is wait and try again the next day.

The "real time" reports are the only ones that are guaranteed to have data immediately.   However I'm not sure that you'll be able to see any demographics data in the real time reports.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to bear in mind that Demographic data is taken from other google products, and will never be from 100% of your traffic. If you have a small amount of traffic, GA may just not collect enough demographic data to make a report